# Accessing Nuxt plugin function in vuex getter

Tags: javascript, plugins, vuex, nuxt.js

I am getting started with nuxtjs and vuex. I just encountered an issue accessing a combined injected plugin function from a getter. E.g.:

*nuxt.config.js*

```
...
plugins: [
  '~/plugins/myplugin.js'  
  ],
...
```

*~/plugins/myplugin.js*

```
function doSomething(string) {
        console.log("done something: " + string)
    }

export default ({ app }, inject) => {
    inject('doSomething', (string) => doSomething(string))
  }
```

*~/store/index.js*

```
export const actions = {
    someAction({commit}) {
        this.$doSomething("Called from Action") // works
    }
}

export const getters = {
    someGetter: state => {
        this.$doSomething("Called from Getter") // throws error
    }
}
```

The code works for the action `someAction` but the call in getter `someGetter` will result in a error suggesting `this` is undefined.

The nuxt documentation only shows examples for accessing injected plugin functions from mutations and actions but does not explicitly mention that getters can not access plugin functions. Is this even possible in nuxt or is there a good reason not to call a plugin method in a getter? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't try to `do_something` in a getter. Getters are for deriving state from your store's state only. The point being that you don't have to separately store and keep up-to-date the derived state. For example you have a list of tasks and you have a getter for completed tasks instead of a separate list of done tasks: `completedTasks: state => state.tasks.filter(task => task.completed)`.

Mutations should only be used for mutating your store's state.

Finally, in actions you can interact with whatever you need, like a webserver API somewhere or `this.$do_something` and then fire off mutations to update the state based on the results.

So I'd say it makes sense what Nuxt is doing here, to inject in the actions but not to the getters.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I guessed that it is considered a bad practice, but could not find any explicit statement about it. Your answer made that point clear. My use case was the following: The getter would be used to retrieve some data from the state and format it for further usage (getter may be named `getDataFormatted`). Since the code doing the formatting may be used in other places/stores I thought it would be best to provide it via plugin keeping everything dry. But I can see your point and guess the formatting should preferably be done where the data is used in the end.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and I was able to get around it by doing

```
export const getters = {
  someGetter: state => {
    $nuxt.$doSomething("Called from Getter") // Grab $nuxt from the global scope
  }
}
```

Not sure if this works in SSR mode however

Comment: It might work and of course I don't know your use case, but I don't think you should be doing this :-) Like I highlighted in my answer, I think getters should just be used to derive state from the store's state.

Comment: You certainly have a good point. In my case the "derived" state depended on a parameter and I needed to do something with that parameter. for example 
getSeries: (state) => (parameter) => { return state[getKeyFromParameter(parameter)] }
Not sure if having getters with parameters is a good idea after all

Comment: Yeah then you use a getter that returns a function, like your `getSeries`. But if you need something out of Nuxt, I'd pass it to the getter function at the call site instead of fishing it out of $nuxt in the getter. That keeps your getters nicely decoupled from Nuxt and anything else except the state.